Items-center not working in tailwind nextjs
"use client";

import Link from 'next/link';
import { usePathname } from 'next/navigation';

const Navbar = () => {
    const pathname = usePathname();
  return (
    <nav className='min-h-10 h-12 bg-black px-24'>
        <div className='flex justify-around items-center'>
            <h1 className='font-bold text-white text-2xl'>Profile</h1>
            <ul className='flex justify-center items-center text-gray-400 gap-6'>
                <li>
                    <Link className={`${pathname === '/' ? 'active' : ''}`} href={'/'}>
                        Home
                    </Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <Link className={`${pathname === '/more' ? 'active' : ''}`} href={'/more'}>
                        More
                    </Link>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
     
    </nav>
  )
}

export default Navbar;

The navbar items are not aligning along y-axis even though i have used items-center. I am not sure why this is happening can anyone help. I am stuck here.

Please provide a screenshot of your current situation

Is this issue actually related to next.js? Please post a [mre] with the generated HTML and not the template

It is because you didn't apply flexbox css to the container element which is nav in your case. Once you add items-center to your nav element, it will work.
"use client";

import Link from 'next/link';
import { usePathname } from 'next/navigation';

const Navbar = () => {
    const pathname = usePathname();
  return (
    <nav className='flex justify-around items-center min-h-10 h-12 bg-black px-24'>
        <h1 className='font-bold text-white text-2xl'>Profile</h1>
        <ul className='flex text-gray-400 gap-6'>
            <li>
                <Link className={`${pathname === '/' ? 'active' : ''}`} href={'/'}>
                    Home
                </Link>
            </li>
            <li>
                <Link className={`${pathname === '/more' ? 'active' : ''}`} href={'/more'}>
                    More
                </Link>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
  )
}

export default Navbar;


An element can be placed in the middle if it has enough space
Here, the parent element has a certain height, but the child has nine, so it doesn't fit all of it, and we need a height equal to the total height of the parent element in order to be in the middle of it.
You just need to add a full height to it.
<div className='flex justify-around items-center h-full'>

